# Errors thrown in C++ basic program

Tags: c++, syntax-error, raspberry-pi, geany

I'm a bit of a newbie to C++, but I have some programming experience. I made a basic program, following a guide I found on t'internet. It compiled with g++ easily, but when I ran it it threw these errors:

> ./FP.cpp: line 1: //: Is a directory
>   ./FP.cpp: line 3: using: command not found
>   ./FP.cpp: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   ./FP.cpp: line 5:`int main ()'

I'm using Geany on a Raspberry Pi (but using a command line to run the program as the Geany interpreter doesn't work). Here's the program:

```
    // First program in c++
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you tried to execute the `.cpp` file, you need to execute the binary produced by g++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to execute the source file, i.e. run it as a shell script.

To *compile* your program you would do something like this:

```
$ g++ -Wall FP.cpp -o FP
```

This produces an *executable* named `FP`. So you should now see both the original program, `FP.cpp`, and the executable, `FP`, in your current directory.

To *run* the executable (compiled program):

```
$ ./FP
```

Comment: Note that the default executable name is `a.out`. So if you don't provide the `-o` option, you can run the program with `./a.out`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling ./FP.cpp tries to execute the source code, which is not what you want. You need to compile it via g++, and then run the executable (usually ./FP)